# Scala Play security issue

Tags: security, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to develop web site, using scala play and finded 1 ussue during "login page".

I'm asking login and password, then i store password with help of this code:

Redirect(routes.UserPage.form(useremailverify.username)).withSession("name" -> useremailverify.username,"guid" -> md5hash1)

But suddenly i finded out that it is gloabal session! It's global to all users. You just could check it navigating http://pickti.me/emailVerificationForm, where you'll se in right top corner that you're logged in already! Does any1 know how to create this sessions new for each users ?

UDP 1:
On form i check if user logged that way:

```
request =>
  request.session.get("name").map { userName =>
    username = userName
  }
```

so if username is not blank - user is logged in

UPD 2:
If i'll try:

Redirect(routes.UserPage.form(useremailverify.username)).newSession.withSession("name" -> useremailverify.username,"guid" -> md5hash1)

I get compilation error:

value newSession is not a member of play.api.mvc.SimpleResult[play.api.mvc.Results.EmptyContent]

UPD 3:
Code:
Redirect(routes.UserPage.form(usersignin.email)).withNewSession("name" -> usersignin.email,"guid" -> md5hash1)

Error:

play.api.mvc.PlainResult does not take parameters

Whithout error is only (but this code dont save data for more than 1 navigation):
                  Redirect(routes.UserPage.form(usersignin.email)).withNewSession.flashing("name" -> usersignin.email,"guid" -> md5hash1)

UPD 4:

Correct way to use withNewSession (BUT it didn't solve main problem...): 
Redirect(routes.UserPage.form(useremailverify.username)).withNewSession.withSession("name" -> useremailverify.username,"guid" -> md5hash1)

UPD 5:

Coockie PLAY_SESSION contains that: "043455c05b1481c501a61167f5dd09e7ec73e693-name=starbucks%40picktime.ru&guid=d7d4c9c3f078d150effbef5e0706c557", so data is gathered from cookie... =(

UDP 6:

Changed version of Play Framework to 2.2.1, but problem is still alive.

Comment: The code looks correct, it should be user-specific. I would also add a `.newSession.withSession(...)` just to make sure the user is starting with a fresh session. How are you checking which user is logged in on the emailVerifcationForm page? Could you maybe update your answer with that code snippet?

Comment: Added in question content a bit more description. i'll try to add .newSession

Comment: Check build in example with `Secured` trait in Zentaks app. It almost you have done but using `play.api.mvc.Security` helper.

Comment: Added UPD 2 part in description

Comment: The idea was to do it without helper, but i checked Zentaks.. It looks  similar probably...

Comment: May be there are other ways to create new session?

Comment: You should use `withNewSession` instead of `newSession`

Comment: Yes, aim is right. Sorry, didn't look it up. Everything looks good from here. Report back if it's still not working.

Comment: Added UPD 3, probably dont works... What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Aded UPD 4. Changed code, but main problem is still alive.

Comment: Is it good idea to use something like that Cache.set(“key_” + id, product, “30mn”); ?

Comment: Can you please change your code, to use the same constructs as provided in the official documentation's `trait Secured`: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaSecurity Especially check the `def withAuth` method, because it makes a call to: `Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized)`. I think your error lies there.

Comment: How do you generate your (top) navigation (В сети как)? The response of your play site contains 'В сети как: starbucks@picktime.ru' WITHOUT ANY session/cookie in the request/response.

Comment: I just show that username value which is described in UPD 1. It IS getting from session, but (i don't know why) session is 1 for ALL users =(

Comment: I follow by your link in topic and application suggest me log in. So session is not shared by all users.

Answer (score 0):

withSession does not set the cookie for all the users. So i think your check is not OK.
I am working on a new Security Framework for Play with name PlayGuard!
You can use this framework or You can see its code and solve your problem.

https://github.com/psycho-ir/PlayGuard-module

Comment: About which check are you speaking? I probably dont want yo use other frameworks and plugins. Even because they are not secure.

Comment: So you're anwer is not a sollution

Comment: Just added PLAY Cookie, to prove that.

Comment: I said you can see its code that shows how you can use cookie ( session ) for your authentication. Don't use this framework but its simple code can help you